# JavaScript piece of code

Tags: javascript

Can some one tell me what is meant by the following piece of code ?

```
            var config = {
                openSocket: function(config) {

                },
                onRemoteStream: function(media) {

                },
                onRoomFound: function(room) {

                },
                onNewParticipant: function(numberOfParticipants) {

                }
            };
```

I have removed most of the content. I just want to know whether the above are object method definitions or what.

Comment: It's an _Object_ with `4` properties, each property is a _function_ with `1` parameter.

Comment: Don't add random tags to questions please.

Comment: Please have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply an `Object` that store 4 functions, so you can call them with:

```
config.openSocket('config data');
config.onRemoteStream('media data');
```

an so on

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if i write the following function and call it does not work.

myFunction: function() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello!";
};

Comment: @user2389323: Maybe you are calling the function before the element with that ID exists.

Comment: try to log the element before setting the `innerHTML` `console.log(document.getElementById("demo"));`

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue when i come from other language to javascript. your code is identical to following code in C#

```
class config{

    public void function openSocket(var config){

    }

    public void function onRemoteStream(var media){

    }

    public void function onRoomFound(var room){

    }

    public void function onNewParticipant(var numberOfParticipants){

    }
}
```

but assume it as a class that already instantiated. so there is no need to `new config()`

you can right away like this : `config.opensocket(confgi);`